I created a diagram using quiver tool but when I compile it clashes
The quiver editor shows me this

But when I copy, paste and compile in a blank overleaf project, I get this

This is the code I'm using
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\usepackage{quiver}  

\begin{document}

\[\begin{tikzcd}
    F &&& F \\
    &&&& {} \\
    {K(s_2,...,s_n)(T)} & {} & {} & {K(s_2,...,s_n)(s_1)} \\
    & {K(T)} \\
    {K(s_2,...,s_n)} &&& {K(s_2,...,s_n)}
    \arrow["{\textrm{alg.} \\ ( \textrm{transit.})}"{description}, hook, from=3-1, to=1-1]
    \arrow[shorten <=2pt, Rightarrow, from=3-2, to=3-3]
    \arrow[hook', from=3-4, to=1-4]
    \arrow["{\textrm{alg.} \\ (T \textrm{ base})}"', hook, from=4-2, to=1-1]
    \arrow[hook', from=4-2, to=3-1]
    \arrow["{\textrm{alg.}}", curve={height=-30pt}, hook', from=5-1, to=1-1]
    \arrow["{\textrm{alg.} \\ \textrm{(si no, abs)}}"', hook', from=5-1, to=3-1]
    \arrow["{\textrm{alg.}}", curve={height=-30pt}, from=5-4, to=1-4]
    \arrow["{\textrm{alg.} \\ (\textrm{transit.})}"', hook', from=5-4, to=3-4]
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}

Do someone know why this is happening?

Welcome to the TeX.SE. I think that LaTeX not produce the same output of an editor.

Very similar: tikz pgf - Linebreak inside label - tikzcd package - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange (except that this question also has the solution of reporting the bug to quiver author) https://github.com/varkor/quiver/issues/225

Update: the quiver developer has updated the website, currently it is available in a development version (check the linked issue above). Do report any follow-up issue on GitHub.

You already have all the line breaks indicated in your code. Instead of changing your diagram, you can simply enable them with
\tikzcdset{
  arrows={align=center}
}

Full MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\usepackage{quiver}  

\tikzcdset{
  arrows={align=center}
}

\begin{document}

\[\begin{tikzcd}[sep=large]
    F &&& F \\
    &&&& {} \\
    {K(s_2,...,s_n)(T)} & {} & {} & {K(s_2,...,s_n)(s_1)} \\
    & {K(T)} \\
    {K(s_2,...,s_n)} &&& {K(s_2,...,s_n)}
    \arrow["{\textrm{alg.} \\ (\textrm{transit.})}"{description}, hook, from=3-1, to=1-1]
    \arrow[shorten <=2pt, Rightarrow, from=3-2, to=3-3]
    \arrow[hook', from=3-4, to=1-4]
    \arrow["{\textrm{alg.} \\ (T \textrm{ base})}"', hook, from=4-2, to=1-1]
    \arrow[hook', from=4-2, to=3-1]
    \arrow["{\textrm{alg.}}", curve={height=-60pt}, hook', from=5-1, to=1-1]
    \arrow["{\textrm{alg.} \\ \textrm{(si no, abs)}}"', hook', from=5-1, to=3-1]
    \arrow["{\textrm{alg.}}", curve={height=-60pt}, from=5-4, to=1-4]
    \arrow["{\textrm{alg.} \\ (\textrm{transit.})}"', hook', from=5-4, to=3-4]
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}



Thank you! This worked perfectly

@nataliasampedro You're welcome!

I have done some edits of your code, only of the left figure. I have added an array to write the text in two rows.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\usepackage{quiver}  

\begin{document}

\[\begin{tikzcd}
    F &&& F \\
    &&&& {} \\
    {K(s_2,...,s_n)(T)} & {} & {} & {K(s_2,...,s_n)(s_1)} \\
    & {K(T)} \\
    {K(s_2,...,s_n)} &&& {K(s_2,...,s_n)}
    \arrow["{\arraycolsep=1pt\def\arraystretch{0.8}\begin{array}{c} \textrm{alg.} \\ \textrm{(transit.)}\end{array}}"{description}, hook, from=3-1, to=1-1]
    \arrow[shorten <=2pt, Rightarrow, from=3-2, to=3-3]
    \arrow[hook', from=3-4, to=1-4]
    \arrow["{\arraycolsep=1pt\def\arraystretch{.8}\begin{array}{c} \textrm{alg.} \\ \textrm{($T$ base)}\end{array}}"', hook, from=4-2, to=1-1]
    \arrow[hook', from=4-2, to=3-1]
    \arrow["{\arraycolsep=.5pt\begin{array}{c} \textrm{alg.}\\ \end{array}}", curve={height=-50pt}, hook', from=5-1, to=1-1]
    \arrow["{\arraycolsep=1pt\def\arraystretch{0.8}\begin{array}{c} \textrm{\quad alg.} \\ \quad \textrm{(si no, abs)}\end{array}}"', hook', from=5-1, to=3-1]
    \arrow["{\textrm{alg.}}", curve={height=-30pt}, from=5-4, to=1-4]
    \arrow["{\textrm{alg.} \\ (\textrm{transit.})}"', hook', from=5-4, to=3-4]
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}



This was a bug in the quiver diagram editor, which was not previously able to export diagrams containing line breaks. This has been fixed as of version 1.5.1. If you reopen your diagram in the editor (which you can do by opening the link that was provided with the exported diagram), and re-export it, you will get the correct TikZ output.
In the future, if you encounter problems with quiver output, please report it on the bug tracker, so that it can be fixed.
(Thanks to the other answers for providing solutions in the meantime.)
